# Dell G15 RGB keyboard lights not working on Pop_OS

Tags: keyboard, bios, pop-os

More or less one week ago, I downloaded the mandatory updates on Windows 11 (I set my PC as dual boot with Windows 11 already came from the original manufacturer and I installed the Pop_OS) but last Friday during a local power outage I was using the notebook only through his battery and I could realize that the RGB keyboard lights weren't working on Pop OS unlike before.

When I choose Windows 11 at GRUB on it the RGB keyboard lights are lit by through Alienware Command Center and after restarting the computer they remain lit. But when I choose any of the Pop_OS kernel configurations available, some seconds before the GDM screen is displayed the keyboard lights turn off and keep.

I have tried to downgrade my BIOS firmware driver and Alienware Command Center on Windows 11 to try to solve the issue on BIOS and consequently on Pop OS but nothing happened, now I am figuring out if this issue is on Windows/BIOS updates (I don't know if they cause any impact on other systems), the NVIDIA driver on my Pop_OS or any kernel modification.

Is there anything that I should configure on any Pop OS file there to make it work again?

My laptop is a Dell G15 5520.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that after a firmware update on my Pop_OS! some settings changed and consequently, the keyboard light settings also were affected. I have searched and discovered this path:

`/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight`

With the following content:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root input 4096 Nov 11 23:35 brightness
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov 11 23:35 brightness_hw_changed
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Nov 12 02:03 device -> ../../../dell-laptop
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov 11 23:35 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Nov 12 02:03 power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov 12 02:03 start_triggers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov 12 02:04 stop_timeout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Nov 11 23:35 subsystem -> ../../../../../class/leds
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Nov 12 02:03 trigger
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4096 Nov 11 23:35 uevent
```

There is one text file called brightness, open it with any text editor with root privileges and set the content inside the file as 1 instead of 0.

Through this simple update, I solved my issue.